# Wordpress loginform

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I have created a loginform that is displayed on the front page.
Everything works fine except one thing, if you log in with bad information you get redirected to wp-login.php and the error message pans out there.

What i want is so the error message displays at the form on my front page.

Is there way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably(more than likely) a redirect in the wp-login.php file which tells the browser to redirect to wp-login page after a failed login attempt and then display the message.  You could just find where this is called and then redirect back to your form.  Just search for "wp-login" in the wp-login.php file

I did this and found many instances of where the user is redirected back to wp-login after failed attempts.